# Convert Selenium IDE Syntax to Python Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium IDE it tells me to use the command

`selectWindow`

and that the target is:

`name={"id":"a52b0dc5-b1f5-2020-01db-139f01c0204a","containerVersion":"7-GA","webContextPath":"/345","preferenceLocation":"https:/url/345/prefs","relayUrl":"https:/url/o345/is/eas/rpc_relay.uncompressed.html","lang":"en_US","currentTheme":{"themeName":"a_default","themeContrast":"standard","themeFontSize":12},"345":true,"layout":"desktop","url":"/brvt","guid":"260f0022-66de-a78b-3ce8-8de63a3bdbec","version":1,"locked":false}`

How do I convert this in python using `driver.switch_to_window` ?

I have tried:

```
driver.switch_to_window(driver.find_element_by_name("{"id":"a52b0dc5-b1f5-2020-01db-139f01c0204a","containerVersion":"7-GA","webContextPath":"/345","preferenceLocation":"https:/url/345/prefs","relayUrl":"https:/url/o345/is/eas/rpc_relay.uncompressed.html","lang":"en_US","currentTheme":{"themeName":"a_default","themeContrast":"standard","themeFontSize":12},"345":true,"layout":"desktop","url":"/brvt","guid":"260f0022-66de-a78b-3ce8-8de63a3bdbec","version":1,"locked":false}"))
```

Suggestions?

Comment: It seems that there are different ways in IDE and WebDriver to identify objects... If you want to know for sure how to select window: click right button on required window and click on "explore element's code" or something like this (depends on browser) to get html source code. Copy it and update your question with this part of code, then I could tell you correct selector to use in Python script

Comment: Painfully easy method to switch between windows (2 ideally) https://gist.github.com/ab9-er/08c3ce7d2d5cdfa94bc7. Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A painfully easy method to switch between windows (2 ideally) [gist.github.com/ab9-er/08c3ce7d2d5cdfa94bc7](https://gist.github.com/ab9-er/08c3ce7d2d5cdfa94bc7).

```
def change_window(browser):
    """
    Simple window switcher without the need of playing with ids.
    @param browser: Current browser instance
    """
    curr = browser.current_window_handle
    all_handles = browser.window_handles
    for handle in list(set([curr]) - set(all_handles)):
        return browser.switch_to_window(handle)
```